# QGIS and Mapinfo reporting different projections for some files

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, mapinfo, epsg, ogrinfo

When I open a tab file that's been generated in QGIS using EPSG 28355 (MGA 94, z55s) using QGIS 3.10 the projection is transformed to 5551

[image]

But when I open it in Mapinfo v17 it's correctly reported as 28355
[image]

ogrinfo thinks that it's EPSG:9122 and 9001
[image]

This is not just one dataset, it's been happening to any data that starts in 28355 or 28354.

It works fine for shp/gpkg etc...the issue is just with the .tab format.

As per my comment to a reply -this has been happening in all QGIS 3x versions and the test is simple.

1. Create a temp table in 28355
   [image]
2. Add some data
   [image]
3. Save it as a tab file and a shp file using save-as rather than "Make Permanent"
4. In a new project try and bring the data in. The SHP is fine but the TAB asks to transform.

TAB
[image]

SHP
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Issue with the latest QGIS, you wont encounter this if you use 3.8 or earlier. I believe it has something to do with the latest version of Proj

Comment: Tested here in the latest QGIS long-term release 3.4.13, compiled against PROJ 6.2.1 and GDAL 3.0.2, same as QGIS 3.10.0, and the EPSG:28355 is well recognized for a file exported as MapInfo TAB. Even so, the PROJCS tag remains "unnamed" for ogrinfo.

Comment: I'm not a mapINFO user but have worked extensively with 28354 and 28355 (everything from 28349 to 28356 over time) which are all on the way out, soon it will be 7854 and 7855 for MGA2020 zone 54 and 55 respectively. If this is causing a serious issue perhaps define as 32755 (WGS84 UTM Zone 55 South) which is more uniform and see if the problem persists - it could be that the MapINFO TAB driver is finding it difficult to read the coordinate information from the most recent TAB files and this CRS is probably near enough for most datasets and purposes except the sub-metre accurate.

Comment: So what you're saying is that 'newer' isn't necessarily 'better' MapInfoNewbie.. this wouldn't be the first time I've seen the most recent version introducing errors in workflows that have had no previous problems. I like that enough for a +1 but don't have MapINFO to test it on.

Comment: Thanks but this has been happening for all versions of QGIS from 3 onwards. I just kept letting it be hoping that it would get fixed but it keeps happening. The test is simple... create a temp table in QGIS save in 28355 as tab and shp, close QGIS and open it and you will see the tab comes up in 5551. See updated Q for details.

Comment: The same problem with Balkans projections, qgis 3.10??

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca what was the test you ran?

Comment: @GeorgeC Project some vector layer with features to a GeoPackage file in EPSG:28355, then export it to MapInfo TAB file. QGIS 3.4.13 open the tab file with EPSG:28355, QGIS 3.10.0 with EPSG:5551. ogrinfo reads "unnamed" PROJCS for both tab files.

Comment: Tried this as well -same issue. Even if you don't consider ogrinfo and just look at the projection in QGIS in the properties--information tab it shows 5551.

Comment: @MichaelStimson I have encountered a ton of workflow issues with qgis updates over the last year or so. Generally the 3.x.0 release introduces a bunch of bugs that are resolved in the future updates. In my team, we are very careful with updating qgis. I suspect 3.10.2 or something will resolve this.

Comment: @MapInfoNewbie that is one of the reasons why I tend not to update *any* software until at least service pack 1 is available for a new major version... I choose not to participate in an informal beta-2 test phase, especially for paid software.  I had noticed I'm getting a lot of 'user' projections, with all the correct parameters as 'human readable' strings when loading some data types into the canvas, though I'd dismissed that as poorly defined data CRS but, as you say, it may be part of a more systemic problem.